# How to make subquery that checks all the months in table?

Tags: sql, subquery

I need to make a query that can do the following thing:
In which month(s) of the year 2018 is the average score higher than the average score in the month of November (also year 2018)?

It relates to the following tables:

**Contentment**

```
EmployeeID, QuestionID, Date, Score
```

**Question**

```
QuestionID, QuestionCat, Question
```

My approach is as following:

```
select month(date) from contentment c
join question q on c.questionid= q.questionid
where year(date) = 2018
group by date
having avg(score) >
(
   select avg(score) from contentment co
   join question qu on co.questionid= qu.questionid
   where month(date) = 11
   and year(date) = 2018
)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc, etc, etc?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select month(date)
from contentment c join
     question q
     on c.questionid= q.questionid
where year(date) = 2018
group by month(date)
having avg(score) > (select avg(score)
                     from contentment co2 join
                          question qu2
                          on co2.questionid = qu2.questionid
                     where month(date) = 11 and year(date) = 2018
                    );
```

In other words, the only apparent issue with your query is the `group by` clause.

That said, I have other recommendations:

- Qualify *all* column names.  That is, add the table alias.  What table does `date` come from?  Score?
- Use date ranges rather than functions on columns, so `date >= '2008-01-01' and date < '2009-01-01'` instead of `year(date) = 2008`.
- Indent  your queries so you can see the clauses.

Comment: Date comes from the table contentment

I executed your query, but I got the following message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'work' to data type int.
Work is a category of a question, in the table it is the 'QuestionCat' I don't know why I got this message? I'm doing nothing with the QuestionCat?

Comment: @DutchFatBoys . . . The only way that *this* query could generate that error -- assuming there are no views -- would be if `questionid` were a string in one table and an integer in the other.